# Python Classifier Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am quite new to Python and SKLearn. I am trying to make a simple classifier but I am running into a problem. I have been following a few different tutorials but getting an error when I try to use the `.fit` method. I am new to the concept and have tried the documentation but have found that hard to understand, can any one help with me error or point me in the right direction.

My thinking behind the error is that the values are out of range for the dtype, as I have transformed all the missing values or nan values but the error is still arising

**Code**

```
def main():
setup_files()

imputer = Imputer()

#the training data minus id and type:
t_num_data = load_csv(training_set_file_path, range(1, 17))
t_num_data_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(t_num_data)
print(t_num_data_imputed)

#the training type column
t_type_col = load_csv(training_set_file_path, 17, dtype=np.dtype((str, 5)))
#the query data minus id and type:
q_data = load_csv(queries_file_path, range(1, 17))
#the query id column
q_id = load_csv(queries_file_path, 0, dtype=np.dtype((str, 10)))


#fit data above to DTC and predict import
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
model.fit_transform(t_num_data, t_type_col)
predictions = model.predict(q_data)


#output the predictions:
with open(solutions_file_path, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(predictions)):
        f.write("{},{}\n".format(q_id[i], predictions[i]))


#fit data above to DTC and predict import
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
model.fit(t_num_data, t_type_col)
predictions = model.predict(q_data)


#output the predictions:
with open(solutions_file_path, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(predictions)):
        f.write("{},{}\n".format(q_id[i], predictions[i]))
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rory/Desktop/classifier.py", line 71, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/Rory/Desktop/classifier.py", line 60, in main
model.fit_transform(t_num_data, t_type_col)
  File "/Users/Rory/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 458, in fit_transform
return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/Users/Rory/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 154, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
  File "/Users/Rory/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 398, in check_array
_assert_all_finite(array)
  File "/Users/Rory/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 54, in _assert_all_finite
" or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Comment: The error says it all. Your `t_num_data` has inf or nan values. Try printing min/max

Comment: and is there a simple fix to this or does or is it within the data itself?

Comment: @imaluengo when I print max and min I get nan for both

Comment: There might be may reasons.. maybe your data has some missing values for example. You can use the preprocessing module of scikit learn.

Comment: @imaluengo, I have updated the question slightly showing how I have transformed the values but the error is still occuring, is there a way to round off the floats or increase the dtype?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your NaN values. There is a long list of ways to estimate NaNs. You could try:

```
t_num_data.fillna(0)
```

Which will fill all the missing values with 0, and then your classifier will work, but may not be very accurate. There additional methods that take the mean, estimation based on nearest neighbors, etc. But that should get your code working for now.